# Can you identify this purple torso (looks like a bathrobe)

Tags: part-identification

I searched Bricklink for bathrobe and dark turquoise/magenta torso but couldn't find it. Can anyone identify this?
[image]

Answer (score 7):

It's [Dumbledore](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=973px149c01#T=C&C=24)'s torso, from 2001-2002 (in the ancient **Purple** color). The BrickLink descriptions for the torso and legs assembly don't mention "sash" or "robe" or anything useful - just "Dumbledore pattern".

[image: Dumbledore]